# Cron-like scheduler, something between cron and celery

Tags: python, django, cron, celery

I'd like to run periodic tasks on my django project, but I don't want all the complexity of celery/django-celery (with celerybeat) bundled in my project.

I'd like, also, to store the config with the times and which command to run within my SCM.

My production machine is running Ubuntu 10.04.

While I could learn and use cron, I feel like there should be a higher level (user friendly) way to do it. (Much like UFW is to iptables).

Is there such thing? Any tips/advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What about [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) + multiprocessing? Or maybe [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler)?

Comment: What could be easier than using cron? You can store your crontab file in your version control system also.

Comment: @brandizzi: Thanks! APScheduler looks fantastic and it's something I might use in the future. For now, I guess the simple thing to do is to stick with cron.

Comment: @Brian Neal: I will look up how to store the crontab file elsewhere.

Comment: @Brian, It's not always super convenient to ssh into your server to disable or tweak a cronjob. Ideally, this should be done through an intuitive web interface.

Comment: @Cerin I can see that. Depends on your use case and how often you need to change/tweak/disable/add jobs.

Comment: Celery is daunting at first. I've used it with Redis instead of RabbitMQ for a smaller footprint. Of course you don't get all the features but it works well for many sites. And you'll find many uses for Redis once you have it up and running.

Comment: @BrianNeal I've been meaning to use redis, but I'll probably wait until 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, i would learn how to use cron. This won't take more than 5 to 10 minutes, and it's an essential tool when working on a Linux server.

What you could do is set up a cronjob that requests one page of your django instance every minute, and have the django script figure out what time it is and what needs to be done, depending on the configuration stored in your database. This is the approach i've seen in other similar applications.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph, but the second seems awfully inefficient. Why not just make cron call certain custom management commands at the specified times? You could even generate and install the crontab file from within Django.

Comment: yes, this was my approach to "keeping the cron configuration simple", which might be better if you're not used to cron. Generating the crontab from within django would be my prefered approach as well, but it's a bit more complicated (permissions, security considerations when accepting user input etc)

Comment: I actually really like that suggestion. I'd hardly call requesting a single view and querying the database every minute inefficient...

Comment: @dgel, inefficient in the sense that you now have to write all the scheduling code yourself instead of relying on a thoroughly debugged and very flexible solution (the cron daemon).

Comment: Seems like sticking with cron is the best way to do it. Requesting a view to do the task would be very inefficient (in my use case), as I'm not really sure about the task completion within the script timeout and it would hold a process thread that would be otherwise serving stuff to actual users. Django already provides a really nice way to execute stuff "off line" (django management commands).

Answer (score 2):

There are several Django-based scheduling apps, such as [django-chronograph](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/) and [django-chroniker](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker) and [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/). I forked django-chronograph into django-chroniker to fix a few bugs and extend it for my own use case. I still use Celery in some projects, but like you point out, it's a bit overcomplicated and has a large stack.

Comment: Thanks, Cerin! Watched your repo on github, might go with it.